# No OpenCL compatible devices were found QGIS

Tags: qgis, opencl

System:
Windows 11, Intel i9,
NVIDIA RTX 3090 24GbRAM
OpenCL 3.0 CUDA 12.3.68 FULL_PROFILE
Driver 545.92

QGIS ver:
QGIS 3.28.15 Firenze

The system reports OpenCL in Geeks3D GPU Caps Viewer. However when I try to enable Acceleration (Settings\Options\Acceleration) if I click on the 'Enable OpenCL acceleration' it displays "No OpenCL compatible devices were found on your system"

I have seen old questions about this but this is a new system, OS, drivers, QGIS installation etc.

Is there a current solution to this?

Comment: try deleting (take a backup first)  C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\opencl.dll https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30931